# What's the meaning of "on the offended bus"?

Tags: expressions

> Some people *jump on the offended bus* at every opportunity.

Is it an idiom? I couldn't find the expression in a dictionary.

Comment: Please cite your source.

Answer (score 4):

“jump on the X bus” is an idiom meaning to join the group of people who are/do X. See also: [bandwagon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bandwagon)

Comment: I assume that in OP's context, the idea is that people are jumping on the *"**I am offended**!"* bandwagon. Probably *specifically* the latest one, which seems to based on the rather curious idea that it's a basic human ***right*** not to be offended (so anyone who offends you must be silenced / deplatformed).

Comment: +1 if you post a link for "bandwagon", it's nicer to post links instead of asking learners to google it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done.

Comment: 'Jumping on the offended bus' is right-wing coded language used to downplay the importance of people's opinions that don't match the conservative agenda. Other things include calling them 'social justice warriors', alleging that they are 'virtue signalling', and invoking a mysterious 'cancel culture'.

Comment: If anyone votes up this comment, I'll work up my comments above into an answer. I may anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - doesn't everyone have the right to state their opinion about an issue, including whether they feel offended? And is it not true that no-one has the right to be agreed with? If I don't buy the Daily Mail, or click Google News links to its website, am I 'silencing' its opinion writers? If I unfriend or block someone on social media, am I 'silencing' them too?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sure, everyone's entitled to their opinion, and broadly speaking they're entitled to *express* that opinion - including the specific case where the opinion is "**I am offended**!" All I said was I don't hold with the notion that anyone has a right ***not*** to be offended. Except insofar as we have laws prohibiting certain behaviours - so you could perhaps claim the "right" to be offended by indecent exposure from a raincoat flasher, but *only because what he's doing is already defined as a criminal offence*. If you're not breaking the law, giving offence is not a crime.

Comment: But the notion that "anyone has a right not to be offended" is in itself ridiculous. has anybody seriously put it forward? Isn't it a straw man erected by right wingers and the like to justify racist/sexist/non-inclusive etc discourse?